# How to use the __subclasscheck__ magic method?

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.x, subclassing, metaclass

How can we make a class who lies about who he has subclassed?

After reading the [doc](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks) I've attempted this:

```
>>> class AllYourBase(type):
...     @classmethod
...     def __subclasscheck__(cls, other):
...         return True
...     
>>> class AllYour(object):
...     __metaclass__ = AllYourBase
```

Now, this class should report that all your base are belong to him.

But it didn't work:

```
>>> issubclass(AllYour, int)
False
```

Why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want `AllYour` to claim to be a subclass of every class, that isn't possible. `__subclasscheck__` works in the other direction.

If you want `AllYour` to claim that every class subclasses it, remove the `@classmethod` decorator, and switch the arguments in the `issubclass` call. Special methods you define on a metaclass don't need special decoration.

Comment: Indeed, the `@classmethod` would mean that the *metaclass* would be passed to `__subclasscheck__()`. You want a regular instance method (the instance being the `AllYour` class).

Comment: Removing this decorator didn't change the behaviour

Comment: @wim: Upon closer inspection, it appears the arguments are in the wrong order in your `issubclass` call. [Fixing that produces a result of `True`.](http://ideone.com/9Db79H) If you want a class that claims to be a subclass of every class, rather than claiming every class subclasses it, that isn't possible.

Comment: Oh, right.  I wanted the other way.  Can we monkeypatch `type.__subclasscheck__` ?

Comment: @wim: Maybe if you screw with ctypes the right way. It'd be really fragile, though. I tried patching `type.__subclasscheck__` by using `gc.getreferents(type.__dict__)[0]` to get through the dict_proxy, but it just crashes Python.

Comment: Are you sure that removing the classmethod decorator is necessary?  `issubclass(int, AllYour)` is returning True even with it there.  You were definitely right about the order of the arguments being flipped though.

Comment: @wim: It happens to work anyway, but with `@classmethod`, `__subclasscheck__` is receiving `AllYourBase` instead of `AllYour` as the `cls` argument. That's not what you want.