# Catch exception by __cause__

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Python 3 allows raising exceptions from other exceptions e.g.:

```
try:
  raise CustomException()
except CustomException as e:
  try:
    raise TypeError() from e
  except TypeError as e:
    print(type(e.__cause__))
```

The `CustomException` instance is stored in the exception object's `__cause__` attribute.
The code above should print `CustomException`.

Is there a way to catch the original exception instead of the newly raised one?

```
try:
  raise CustomException()
except CustomException as e:
  try:
    raise TypeError() from e
  except CustomException as e:
    print(type(e)) # should reach here
```

Overriding `__subclasscheck__` does not work since I don't have access to the instance and I it is impossible to specify that [CustomException is a subclass of all classes or of the **cause** class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34623653/85140).

Is there a way to trick Python into thinking that the exception we're catching is of the type of `__cause__`?

Comment: If you want to catch `CustomException ` why do you bother to raise `TypeError`?

Comment: The custom exception is used to catch all exceptions and return a Failure container instead. https://github.com/dry-python/returns/blob/master/returns/functions.py#L50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have control over the exception that is raised you can perhaps make it a subclass of the raised exception:

```
try:
   raise TypeError()
except TypeError as e:
   try:
      class CustomException(TypeError.__class__):
         pass
      raise CustomException() from e
   except TypeError as e:
      print(type(e))  # Reaches here
```

That said, the mechanism of catch-and-reraise is meant to *hide* what the original exception was so that later code doesn't depend on implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: catch all exceptions and filter required:

```
try:
    raise ZeroDivisionError()
except ZeroDivisionError as e:
    try:
        raise TypeError() from e
    except Exception as ex:
        if type(ex.__cause__) is ZeroDivisionError:
            print('ZeroDivisionError')
        else:
            raise  # re-raise exception if it has different __cause__
```